# Elsevier paper article class does not work with all ASCII-characters and package inputenc (Unicode char ³ (U+B3))

Tags: templates, unicode, input-encodings

Umlauts like "ä, ö, ü" and diacritics like "á, ó ,.." cannot be displayed.

The class `elsarticle.cls` can be downloaded [here](https://www.elsevier.com/authors/author-schemas/latex-instructions).

When including `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` in the preamble,
the following error occurs:

```
Package inputenc: Unicode char ³ (U+B3)
(inputenc)  not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

What can I do about this issue and is there any source of *Elsevier*-paper-classes and related `LaTeX`-templates, which allows for any type of characters, i.e. `utf-8` encoding?

Comment: If you don't use too many Unicode characters then you could set them up manually, for example `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00B3}{\textsuperscript{3}}` in the preamble. Note this assumes that ³ is used only in text mode and that inside a math expression you use `^3`.

Comment: Is `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` still required?

Comment: And how do I include Umlauts like "ä, ö, ü" and diacritics like "á, ó ,.."?

Comment: They are available by default if you load `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`. Just type them in your document as unicode characters. Note that on newer LaTeX installations (from 2018) the utf8 encoding is default and you don't need to include the `inputenc` package anymore, however if you want to declare extra characters like ³ then you still need the package.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Marjin I can now execute my LaTeX-document without errors including
`\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}` and `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` in my preamble.

All I had to add to the preamble was `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00B3}{\textsuperscript{3}}`.