# Package inputenc: Unicode character ≤ (U+2264) (inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX - Error caused by unnoticed literal "≤"

Tags: unicode, math-operators, input-encodings, compilation-error

When trying to build my `LaTeX`-file with [latexmk](https://ctan.org/pkg/latexmk?lang=en) in `VS Code` using [Latex Workshop extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=James-Yu.latex-workshop), the following error is thrown:

```
Package inputenc: Unicode character ≤ (U+2264) (inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

This happens even though my `LaTeX`-file encoding is `UTF-8`, and the package `inputenc` is given the option `utf8` (see following excerpt of my preamble):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-sc}

%%%%%%%% SPRACH- UND FONTPAKETE %%%%%%%%
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% * Declare special unicode characters which lead to errors otherwise * %
% Docs: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/558402/elsevier-paper-article-class-does-not-work-with-all-ascii-characters-and-package
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00B3}{\textsuperscript{3}}
...
```

As can be seen, I've already had a problem with another Unicode character `00B3`.
The character in question this time is ["is less than or equal to"](https://oeis.org/wiki/List_of_LaTeX_mathematical_symbols#Relation_operators), i.e. in `LaTeX` it'd be `\leq`, or in unicode [U+2264](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2264).

The affected part in my `LaTeX`-script appears twice almost in the same way like so:

```
[...]
The measurement accuracy related to $\textrm{H}_{2}\textrm{S}$ is either $\leq
\pm 3 \, \%$ or $\leq \pm 0.5 \, \textrm{ppm}$, whichever is the greater value.
[...]
```

Moreover, the literal `≤` is present in a table like so:

```
%% Table containing the problematic literal `≤` %%
\begin{table}[ht]
    \caption{.....}
    \label{tab:...}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}lllllllll@{}}
        \cmidrule(r){1-5}
        ....
        Average percentage of measurements $≤ \, \nicefrac{\textrm{D}}{\textrm{T}} \, (\%)$   & 76.7    & 66.7    & 85.7    & 85.7       \\
        ....
    \end{tabular}
....
```

Trying to resolve this problem again in the same way as done with the other unicode character, declaring it specifically in my preamble, didn't work out this time:

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{U+2264}{$\leq$}
```

*I'd like to understand two things:*

1. Main question: how do I get rid of the error and make the LaTeX-file compile correctly?
2. Optional question: why this error came about in the first place, when it had been working flawlessly all the time before?

---

**System specifics:**

Lubuntu 20.04 LTS, VS Code

Comment: You must have a literal "≤" in your input file... the $\leq$ will not trigger that error. Could you possibly post a MWE?

Comment: You definitely shouldn't write `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{U+2264}{$\leq$}`, but at most `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2264}{\leq}`. But as Rmano pointed out,the origin of the error is something else.

Comment: @Rmano you were right, I hadn't noticed someone had sent me a word-table, which I converted to a LaTeX-table. Within that, there was a literal `≤` causing the issue. Now, I replaced it with $\leq$ and it works like a charm.

Comment: note that `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} ` (which isn't needed in current latex) specifies that latex should interpret the bytes in the file as UTF-8 which is why it recognises ≤ as the character U+2264 it does not mean that latex has rules and fonts loaded to typeset every Unicode character

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the first part of your comment is clear to me, but the second part "it does not mean that latex has rules and fonts loaded to typeset every Unicode characte" is not. Could you please elaborate a little further what you mean by that?

Comment: With `utf8`, LaTeX knows that U+2264 is a single character, but it (by default) done not know how to represent it (you need a suitable font and a suitable declaration, like `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2264}{\ensuremath{\leq||` for example. *Without* `utf8`, latex would have read two characters  with code 22 and 64 ...

Comment: @campa I've just included the table containing the literal `≤`

Comment: pdflatex has only 256 characters per font, In luatex (as on this website) for character U+2264 then just output that character in the current font, probably makes  ≤  but in pdftex you need to know which math font to use and which position in that font, so easiest is not to output the character but outpit the classic markup `\leq` and then let the normal tex definitions make whatever character is needed. For leq the font is probably already loaded, you just need to map the unicode character correctly, but if you have 你好，世界 (hello world in Chinese) then loading fonts for pdftex is more involved

Comment: Generic question: [Entering Unicode characters in LaTeX - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34604/entering-unicode-characters-in-latex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Rmano pointed out correctly in the first comment of my question,
there was an **unnoticed literal** `≤` within a value-table causing the issue.

This came about as I'd incorporated a `Word`-table which I converted into a `LaTeX`-table via the [LaTeX-table-generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/latex_tables).

*The only thing I had to do is* replace the culprit literal `≤` with `$\leq$` to make the document compile with errors.

So beware when inserting contents from external sources into your `LaTeX`-file as they could contain some unusual characters.

Comment: I had the same error, accidentally, when copying a formula I lost the ≤ symbol inside the $a≤5$, when I changed it to $a\leq 5$ the problem was solved.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

One solution is to replace your font packages with `\usepackage{unicode-math}` and compile with LuaLaTeX or XeLateX.  This supports all of Unicode.

Another solution that’s compatible with any TeX engine is:

```
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newunicodechar{≤}{\ensuremath{\leq}}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out different options. I might consider them in the future, if needed.

Comment: Alternatively use utf8x (read comments there) https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34609/250119

Comment: Side note -- "all of Unicode" as long as the *font* has the character, otherwise you get blank space.